# Change html href but leave text same using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, text, href, title

Is there a way to change the href value for a link but leave its text the same?

```
<a id="mylink" href="www.link.com">click here</a>
```

I would like to simply change "www.link.com" and leave the text "click here" untouched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [the `.attr()` function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to change an attribute on an element:

```
$('#mylink').attr('href', 'newvalue');
```

Also, just an FYI (and this may even be why you're changing it), `href="www.link.com"` will result in a broken link, unless there's actually a file called `www.link.com` in the same path as the page hosting the link.  To go to another domain, the URL needs to be fully-qualified to include the protocol: `href="http://www.link.com"`

Comment: We currently have a php function that we use to replace html content, but the function is defined as followed: replaceContent($selector, $content). So right now I'm doing this: replaceContent('#mylink[href]'), 'http://www.link.com'). This seems to replace the text of the link also, which is not desirable. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1074861: I can't really advise you on the use of a PHP function without knowing the code of that function or what it does.  The original question is about changing an element attribute using jQuery, which is very easy.  What you do in PHP is something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery's .attr() method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) would be the best way to go about doing this. It works like a charm. Here's the code you would use for what you want to do:

```
$('#mylink').attr('href', 'http://www.newlink.com');
```

Also, make sure your href includes the protocol. (`http://`, `https://`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery .attr() can implement it easily.

```
var link = $("#mylink");   //the target anchor
link.attr("href","{your url here}");
```